# $ABCD$ is a square, is $P > Q$ or $P < Q$ or $P = Q$ or not enough information?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

[image: Square]

$ABCD$ is a square. Let $Q = 15$. If the side of the square $ABCD$ is $P$, then is $P$:

$1.\quad P > Q\\
 2.\quad P < Q\\
 3.\quad P = Q\\
 4.\quad \text{Not enough information}$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Hint:  The Pythagorean Theorem is your friend.  There are lots of right triangles here.

Comment: I've tried forming the right triangle AEF and CEF, which gives me the hypotenuses $3\sqrt{17}$ and $3\sqrt{10}$ respectively. I'm not really sure how to proceed with these two numbers though

Comment: So, look for more right triangles.  The diagonal is relevant.

Comment: Ah, right. So, if the diagonal goes through $EF$ and say $O$ is the point where $AC$ meets $EF$. Then, I can just use The Phytagorean Theorem to find $AO$ and $CO$. Thus, finding $AC$ and the square's side. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

[image]

As shown in the picture, $AC=\sqrt{21^2+3^2}=\sqrt{450}$ therefore $P=\sqrt{225}=15$